# Python Programming Style: config loading within a separate file?

Tags: python, config, configuration-files

Currently, i have one python file python_file.py. This loads variables from an INI file.

The file is laid out as such:

```
def load_config(section):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    logging.info('Loading config for: %s', section)
    dict = {}
    options = config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict[option] = config.get(section, option)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Exception: ", e)
    return dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sheet = load_config('Sheets')['sheet']
```

Should i perform the config loading in another file or class or is this good style?

Comment: you are using a separate function to load config file this is pretty good. I don't think you should change anything about it

Comment: Path to config file should be passed as a parameter to this function. You can leave `'config.ini'` as default one.  See [What is wrong with magic strings?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/what-is-wrong-with-magic-strings)

Comment: Thanks guys, i will check it out.